# Grails Views not working with .GSP

Tags: grails, view, gsp

I have a customer controller with the generated list function. All works well if I use the scaffolded views, but once I try and access the list function on a generated view, I get no data passed to the page. If I for example type in http://localhost/myproject/customer/list I get a list of customers in the database, however if I type 
http://localhost/myproject/customer/list.gsp I don't get any data.

I have been racking my brain and trying to find an answer in the documents, but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [url mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.4%20URL%20Mappings) in the docs. just change list to list.gsp

e.g.:

```
"/product" {
controller = "product"
action = "list"
}
```

to:

```
"/product.gsp" {
controller = "product"
action = "list"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. I can't thank you enough, I have been beating my head against the computer screen for two day.